# IIS Client Certificate is Not Accepting, Not getting any Certificate Prompt

Tags: iis, .net-core, windows-server-2012

In one of my applications, I enabled the configuration on IIS to accept the client certificate, by enabling like the below picture. The same configuration I did on the local IIS server and it works.

[image]

but it's not working. Any configuration that I am missing..?? At least it should prompt for the Certificate.

Answer (score 0):

It will prompt the client to provide a certificate only when accessing https:

[image]

You need to check whether to access the service via https.

Comment: Yes, I am using HTTPS.

Comment: Is it because SSL was not successfully set up? If you are not prompted to provide a certificate, can you access this page normally? For more information about "How to Set Up SSL on IIS 7", you can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/how-to-set-up-ssl-on-iis

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install the cert in cert store in current user for the browser to show up the dialog box with list of certificates

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).